# How can I target a webform results page to create a panel around?

Tags: webforms, panels, forms

I'm trying to set up a panel for the submitted page for a webform in order to add a sidebar and bottom section. I need help setting up the panel, specifically with how to select the submission (results) page of the webform.

The url of the submitted page looks like this - http://site.localhost/node/2136/done?sid=8

I tried -

```
String: URL path : Current path is "node/2136/*"
```

as well as -

```
String: URL path : Current path is "node/*/done"
```

both were a no go

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there really no separator between the node id, and "done"?

Comment: @Letharion - oops, those lines weren't code wrapped leaving out the '*'

Comment: Sorry, I should have formulated the question better. It's the url you have in the question text I mean, "http://site.localhost/node/2136done?sid=8", I'm guessing there should be a / there as well, between the nid and "done"? Just want to make sure as it makes an important difference.

Comment: nope, looks like this - http://i.imgur.com/xWHUu.png

Comment: Doesn't the built in node_view page work for this? I take it you are trying to create a new one, which won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. After filling out my webform I see my submitted page (at the url in the screenshot above.) I would like to use that page as a node template override panel. So I can add views/boxes/blocks/etc that are available through panels. There must be a way to target that submitted (webform results) page through panels, right? I appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: Hey, re-wrote my answer completely, as the I took a deeper look at it, and figured out why my initial one didn't help you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since webform, for showing results implements a different path than the standard node/%, you need a way to tell Panels to take over this path.

The module [Page manager existing pages](http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) allows you to do this.

Install and enable the module. Go to `admin/structure/pages/existing-pages/add`, find the path `/node/%webform_menu/done` and add it to the list.

Now go to `admin/structure/pages` and you should see a new "task" for results, where you can customize the result page.

As pointed out by winchendonsprings, the results are available under `Add Content >> Existing pages >> Existing page >> node overview`.

In order to do this on a webform by webform basis, one will need to add a manual node context, where you select the webform you want by nid, and then add a selection rule that compares the current context against the manually loaded one.

Normally manually loaded contexts should be avoided as "hardcoding" node id's is rarely a good idea, but this seems like a good exception from the rule, although it will still not be properly exportable.

Comment: Everything here is what I am currently using, except using the node type as webform for the selection. What I am trying to select is not the webform itself, but rather the submitted page after the form is filled out and submitted.

Comment: I see, I would have expected it to work regardless of rendering the form or it's results. Sorry, if that isn't enough, I don't know.

Comment: damn, Thanks for helping though @Letharion

Comment: Thanks, these steps worked. It worked for all webform results pages by default. Any idea on how I can select just the results of a single webform? Also to show results in the panel you will need to - Add Content>>Existing pages>>Existing page>>node overview.

Comment: Answered the "single webform" part, and added your remark about showing results.